# sql query works only for 1 record

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'am really new in sql - since 1 week, and my query works only for 1 record

```
Select m.meal_id, m.name, m.usp, m.description, m.worktime, m.proprietor, m.img, m.url, m.servings, d.name, c.name, s.name, sum(i.price / i.minamount * r.quantity) as mealPrice

from meals m
join recipe r on m.meal_id = r.meal_id
join ingredients i on i.ingredient_id = r.ingredient_id
join difficulty d on d.difficulty_id = m.difficulty_id
join cat c on c.cat_id = m.cat_id
join social s on s.social_id = m.social_id
and m.meal_id = 1
```

This query works for one record, but if I want to have all the meals (without the "and" function) I still get only one record but the sum mealPrice is for all records added, how do I get this query for all meals?

I like for each meal one record with the total sum mealPrice

my tables:

```
    create table meals
(
    meal_id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(100) not null,
    usp varchar(100) not null,
    description varchar(500) not null,
    worktime varchar(100) not null,
    proprietor varchar(100) not null,
    img varchar(100) not null,
    url text not null,
    servings int not null,
    difficulty_id int unsigned not null,
    cat_id int unsigned not null,
    social_id int unsigned not null,
    foreign key (difficulty_id) references difficulty (difficulty_id),
    foreign key (cat_id) references cat (cat_id),
    foreign key (social_id) references social (social_id)
);

create table ingredients
(
    ingredient_id   int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(45) not null,
    minamount float not null,
    price float not null
);

create table recipe
(
    meal_id int unsigned not null,
    ingredient_id int unsigned not null,
    quantity float,
    primary key (meal_id, ingredient_id),
    foreign key (meal_id) references meals (meal_id),
    foreign key (ingredient_id) references ingredients (ingredient_id)

);
```

Comment: What is your MySQL version ?

Comment: Version is 5.5.56

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** Based on [recent edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/52718222/2) by OP; you need to simply do a `GROUP BY`.

Try:

```
Select m.meal_id, 
       m.name, 
       m.usp, 
       m.description, 
       m.worktime, 
       m.proprietor, 
       m.img, 
       m.url, 
       m.servings, 
       d.name, 
       c.name, 
       s.name, 
       SUM(i.price / i.minamount * r.quantity) as mealPrice
from meals m
join recipe r on m.meal_id = r.meal_id
join ingredients i on i.ingredient_id = r.ingredient_id
join difficulty d on d.difficulty_id = m.difficulty_id
join cat c on c.cat_id = m.cat_id
join social s on s.social_id = m.social_id 
GROUP BY m.meal_id, 
         m.name, 
         m.usp, 
         m.description, 
         m.worktime, 
         m.proprietor, 
         m.img, 
         m.url, 
         m.servings, 
         d.name, 
         c.name, 
         s.name
```

---

**Based on [Previous Version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/52718222/1) of OP's Problem:**

This is a [Window function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html) problem. In newer versions of MySQL (**>= 8.0**), you can easily do this. In older version (your version is 5.5), we can solve it using [Session Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html).

Try:

```
Select m.meal_id, 
       m.name, 
       m.usp, 
       m.description, 
       m.worktime, 
       m.proprietor, 
       m.img, 
       m.url, 
       m.servings, 
       d.name, 
       c.name, 
       s.name, 
       (@sum := @sum + (i.price / i.minamount * r.quantity)) as mealPrice
from meals m
join recipe r on m.meal_id = r.meal_id
join ingredients i on i.ingredient_id = r.ingredient_id
join difficulty d on d.difficulty_id = m.difficulty_id
join cat c on c.cat_id = m.cat_id
join social s on s.social_id = m.social_id 
CROSS JOIN (select @sum := 0) AS init
```

---

In MySQL version >= 8.0, we could use `SUM()` as Window function, over a partition of complete resultset. In that case, query would be:

```
Select m.meal_id, 
       m.name, 
       m.usp, 
       m.description, 
       m.worktime, 
       m.proprietor, 
       m.img, 
       m.url, 
       m.servings, 
       d.name, 
       c.name, 
       s.name, 
       SUM(i.price / i.minamount * r.quantity) OVER() as mealPrice
from meals m
join recipe r on m.meal_id = r.meal_id
join ingredients i on i.ingredient_id = r.ingredient_id
join difficulty d on d.difficulty_id = m.difficulty_id
join cat c on c.cat_id = m.cat_id
join social s on s.social_id = m.social_id
```

Comment: oh thanks! but i get an error -" check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@sum := 0) AS init' at line 21"

Comment: @Tomimotmot please check the updated answer. there was a typo

Comment: @Tomimotmot no worries. happy to help :)

Comment: oh, but now I get a record for each ingredient per meal! i only want one record per meal with the total sum of mealPrice

Comment: @Tomimotmot wait - updating. Please update your question to add this detail. As current question does not state that.

Comment: @Tomimotmot do you want results for all the meal_id or just `meal_id = 1` ?

Comment: for my api I need both cases

Comment: @Tomimotmot please check the updated answer - use the very first query.

Comment: my bad, it works -> thank you very much now i can finish my api! :)

Answer (score 0):

you need below query ,cross join helps to you get the desire result

```
Select m.meal_id, 
       m.name, 
       m.usp, 
       m.description, 
       m.worktime, 
       m.proprietor, 
       m.img, 
       m.url, 
       m.servings, 
       d.name, 
       c.name, 
       s.name, 
       (@s := @s + (i.price / i.minamount * r.quantity)) as mealPrice

from meals m
join recipe r on m.meal_id = r.meal_id
join ingredients i on i.ingredient_id = r.ingredient_id
join difficulty d on d.difficulty_id = m.difficulty_id
join cat c on c.cat_id = m.cat_id
join social s on s.social_id = m.social_id 
CROSS JOIN ( select @s:= 0) AS t
```